# @fontface doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010, css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CodeLight';
    src: url("font/CODE_Light.eot"); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url("font/CODE_Light.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url("font/CODE_Light.woff") format("woff"), /* Modern Browsers */
         url("font/CODE_Light.ttf")  format("truetype"), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url("font/CODE_Light.svg#svgFontName") format("svg"); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

I am trying to load above fonts using @font face, but it gives 404 when I checked it in chrome developer tools. Can anyone explain what is wrong with this.

Comment: I am guessing that all files exist at `/font`?

Comment: Probably a parth issue as others have said. If you could provide a link to your site that would help us to diagnose.

Comment: Can you add files tree? Eg. where is `css` stylesheet or font folder in depending of `index.html` file (root folder)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it gives you 404, you've specified a bad url for your fonts...

If you have a directory structure like this:

```
~
    css
           style.css
    fonts
           font1.eot
           font2.ttf
```

Than you obviously have to set it like this:

```
src: url('../fonts/font1.eot")
```

Comment: Yes, but I have used double quotes instead of single.

Comment: @Joshua, type of quotes doesn't matter here :) If you're used to double quotes, it's not a problem. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide full path to your "font" directory  or use a "/" in front of it if located in the root. Like so:

```
src: url("/font/CODE_Light.eot");
...
```